# JQuery mobile: page links unreliable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Playing around with JQuery Mobile... demo example here (in Dutch, but it does not matter):

https://c9.io/pieter78/neurodss/workspace/noac/index.html

If you take the first item (dagibatran) and then the second item on the next page (elective ingrepen) the link does not work. However, if you go directly to the second page:

https://c9.io/pieter78/neurodss/workspace/noac/dagibatran.html

(or simply reload it if you came from the first page) it does work.

In IE I can see that if you click "dagibatran" on the first link, you end up on this URL:
https://c9.io/pieter78/neurodss/workspace/noac/index.html#/pieter78/neurodss/workspace/noac/dagibatran.html

I can understand that this does not work, but I do not understand why this happens. IMHO the code is correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: because jQM loads first page div in each HTML file. So you either separate pages into different html files or use single-page template.

Comment: It does take the first div of the second page correctly, but does not take the next one... So I do not understand how thid could explain the problem.

Comment: Exactly, it takes first div of each HTML file and neglects other divs. Thus, each page should be in a separate html file, or put them all in one html file.

Comment: Then how do I link to new files? I do not want the whole site in one html document, but linking creates the problem I described.

Answer (score 0):

This page shows the solution I was looking for:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/link-formats.html

If you do `<a href="some page.html" data-ajax="false">Click me</a>` then I get the result I want. Otherwise the link will be considered as an AJAX request, and that gives a different experience.